# Edge case: Can a free Object Interaction, which can be taken as part of a movement or action, be taken at the *end* of an action (by RAW)?

Tags: dnd-5e

To set the scenario:
I'm a Rogue, level 4. I start a battle with a single dagger drawn, and when my turn comes, I throw that dagger at my foe. It seems to me that by RAW, I could take my free Object Interaction, as part of my Action, to draw a fresh dagger as I finish throwing the first one (assuming it is not stowed in my pack, and are at easy access) using my free Object Interaction, which can be used as part of an action or movement.

Barring this, I know that I would be able to draw a fresh weapon as part of my Move if I saved some of my Speed for after my Action. But this would create an odd situation where efficient combat requires me to be constantly shifting around in order to draw weapons as part of my Movement.

As far as I know the PHB doesn't specifically rule on this, but it seems to be in keeping the rules as I understand them. Is there any apocrypha or errata that deals with this somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a creature use its "free" interaction with an object during a bonus action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92597/can-a-creature-use-its-free-interaction-with-an-object-during-a-bonus-action)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking about, I think from the way you're describing the situation you may have some misunderstandings about how turns play out in 5e. Could you maybe add a description of an example turn in which the problem you're asking about appears?

Comment: Simplified to its barest bones, I was just asking if I can throw a weapon and then draw another one as part of a single action using my free Object Interaction. It seems pretty clear that I can, because I can take a free Object interaction "In Tandem" [PHB 190] with my action, which doesn't specify how the two behaviors are timed out. I can interact with an object before my action, during (if it would be reasonable to do so), or after my action is complete, so long as the two behaviors happen in tandem with each other, i.e.: They are connected, without another behavior interrupting them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### There is no time limit for the free object interaction.

The section about [Other activities on your turn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn) explains what one can do *during* their action or movement or things that do not require any of them (emphases mine):

> Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that *require neither* your action nor your move.
>
> [...]
>
> You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, *during either* your move or your action.

There is no time indication on *when* you can take these options: for example, if you start your turn in front of a closed (not locked) door, *before* moving you can open it and then pass it. If you want to pass past an open door and close it (not lock it) you can do it *during* your movement, or at the *end* of your movement because you want to stand still behind the door and block it with your body.

In this [section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#BeingProne)<sup>1</sup> one can find the table *Interacting With Objects Around You* that provides examples of things that one can do *in tandem* with action or movement: this means that you can take one of this options (or one that the DM adjudicates suitable as a free object interaction) when you take your action or movement, without specifying the timing (before, during, after).

In your case, you can surely draw another  weapon as part of your movement, if you still have movement left: remember that you can move even for just 1 foot, you do not have to move by multiples of 5 feet.

---

<sup>1</sup> I think that this table is in this particular section because in the printed versions of the PHB it is at the bottom of the left column of the text, which is the one referring to "other activities on your turn" *and* movement.

Comment: OP wants to draw the daggers, if possible, without it counting as part of their movement.  Couldn't they draw them, by your same argument and reasoning, as part of their attack action at the end of their attack without it counting as Move?

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me, yea. While "In Tandem" is not a reserved word in D&D, in plain English it means that the action can be taken at the same time, alongside, or one-after-the-other. And yes, it wouldn't make sense to be limited to opening a door and moving through as opposed to moving through and closing the door. These could be reasonably assumed to be equal acts unless there was some extra step, such as locking the door behind you. This clarifies it for me, at least in the absence of some word-of-god clarification.

Comment: @Kirt In the second paragraph the OP asks if they can draw another weapon as a part of movement, aren't they? Am I missing something?

Comment: @LauraRuby I changed a little bit of the answer to reflect the absence of references to two weapon fighting and Dual Wielder feat.

Comment: @Eddymage OP's 1st paragraph says that they would _like_ to draw the weapons as part of their [attack] Action.  Paragraph 2 says if they _can't_ do that ["Barring that"], _then_ they would like to do it as part of their move.

Comment: @Kirt Ok, I see it now: anyway, I think that the first part of the answer covers that.